# From data frame to dataframe with lists and unique id

Tags: r

Lets say I have following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
                 content = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "red", "black", "white"),
                 content2 = c("cat", "dog", "horse", "cat", "dog", "horse"))
```

I would like to make a dataframe in whch there is as many rows as number of unique id values with other columns collapsed in list.

The output should look like this:

```
output <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                     content = I(list(c("red", "yellow", "blue"), c("red", "black"), c("white", "black"))),
                     content2 = I(list(c("cat", "dog", "horse"), c("cat", "dog"), c("horse", "duck"))))
```

I would also like to know how to go other way again, From `output` to `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
         group_by(id) %>%
         summarise_each(funs(list(.)))
```

To go back to the original dataset

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(res)
```

Comment: For reference, summarise_each is to be deprecated: https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/ I don't know the replacement funs' names or syntax, though.

Comment: @Frank Thank for the link.  I think `summarise_at`  I am not sure if this is the correct way for all the columns `df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_at(names(.), funs(list(.)))`